# How to check content of field in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have table:

```
<c:forEach var="employee" items="${employees}">
    <tr>
        <td>${employee.id}</td>
        <td>${employee.gender.gender}</td>
        <td>${employee.name}</td>
        <td>${employee.surname}</td>
        <c:if test="${employee.appointment.appointment eq NAVIGATOR}">//Checking value of field
            <td>${employee.appointment.appointment}</td>
        </c:if>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to check value of field:

*${employee.appointment.appointment}*

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to put the NAVIGATOR in quotes like 'NAVIGATOR', if you are checking for the value of the employee.appointment.appointment is actually NAVIGATOR.

```
<c:if test="${employee.appointment.appointment eq 'NAVIGATOR'}">
      <td>${employee.appointment.appointment}</td>
</c:if>
```